# What does these headers mean and what are their functions?

Tags: node.js, express

While reading some tutorial I found that

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, PUT');
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
   next();
});
```

What does every res.header mean? and what are their functions?

Comment: They are [CORS headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These headers allow cross-domain access: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Without these headers client scripts are allowed to get data from your server  (edited: in your case you specify request types DELETE and PUT) only if their origin is the same (i.e. your client-side html and javascript are loaded from the same domain name). Scripts from different domains will receive an error like 'this origin is not allowed' or something like that.